# Language code "es-XL" Spanish used in Latin America not Working in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

We have support for multiple languages in our application using resource files with the below language code.

English - en-Us, German - de-DE, Spanish (Latin America) - ex-XL, French - fr-fR

While using Visual Studio 2012 Professional when building resource files solution the respective language code folder dll was created or modified.

But when have shifted to Visual Studio 2019 Profession Edition, the resource files Spanish ex-XL dll are not created with the ex-XL folder so it display English text instead of Spanish. Other language folders were created with respective language codes and displayed content that specifies languages. We have implemented applications in ASP.NET MVC using C# running on .NET framework 4.6.1.

I have installed a Spanish language pack on my machine Spanish (Latin America) and Spanish (Spain). Spanish `es-ES` language code is working fine localization when created POC is not working Spanish with language code `es-XL`.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Your suggestions are welcome.

I have tried create POC with above English, German, Spanish language es-ES, es-Mx language codes are working fine only `es-XL` language code dll is not created in Visual Studio 2019 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is any defined language tag `es-XL`

BCP 47, which is the standard for how language tags are structures doesn't include a generic `XL` subtag.

Two letter region codes have to come from ISO 3166-1.

You can [search the ISO 3166 codes](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search) for something that will be valid.

From [Choosing a Language Tag](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-language-tags) you can see mention of `es-419` meaning Spanish as spoken in Latin America which is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

"XL" is a so-called "private use subtag".
So "es-XL" means "Spanish for a region that you (potentially with some other parties) define for the symbol 'XL'"

For those subtags, according to ISO 3166-1, certain two-letter combinations are reserved:

> AA, QM to QZ, XA to XZ, and ZZ
> (from https://www.iso.org/glossary-for-iso-3166.html)

[RFC5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646.html#section-4.6) also states:

> 'AA', 'ZZ', and those in the ranges 'QM'-'QZ' and 'XA'-'XZ'

And clarifies how they should (not) be used:

> Private use subtags have no meaning outside the private agreement
> between the parties that intend to use or exchange language tags
> that employ them.  The same subtags MAY be used with a different
> meaning under a separate private agreement.  They SHOULD NOT be
> used where alternatives exist and SHOULD NOT be used in content or
> protocols intended for general use.

At work, we also use es-XL for "Spanish as used in Latin America". But that's just the convention we adapted for a set of web tools inside our corporation.

So for some other tools, systems etc. (even in the same company) it could mean something different.

For your specific question:
It is definitely not a standard locale tag, as opposed to the other languages you are using. There might be a way to tell your tools/framework, how to work with this locale (or not).

Otherwise es-419 as suggested by @Dragonthoughts is the proper standard way. It uses the language code according to [UN M49](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M49), which is correct according to [RFC 5646 - 2.4.4-4.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646.html#section-2.2.4)